# Tune system radio app via third party app

Tags: android, fm-radio

I am trying to build an app that will auto tune/switch channels of android's built-in radio app. It's gonna be an AI for radio.  But I don't know if its possible to control a system app via an external app. If its not possible, can someone point me to any API that can be used to make a satellite based radio app ?

Edit: By built-in I meant the radio app that comes pre-loaded in most phones.

Comment: Android does not have a "built-in radio app". There are ~2 billion Android devices, spread across thousands of device models from hundreds of manufacturers. Few have any sort of FM, AM, or shortwave receiving capability. Those that do have *manufacturer-supplied* apps for using those receivers. If you want to work with those receivers, talk to the device manufacturers.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  Do OEMs have their own API for interacting with FM wave receivers or are they provided by android?

Comment: AFAIK, that is not standardized in the AOSP. It would vary by chipset.